# Can anyone explain how this valid C++ program returns null?

Tags: c++

I stumbled upon this [paste](http://paste.lisp.org/display/135584):

```
int main() {
return!!!~!!!!!~!!!1??!??!1?

"^_^"  <:3

]:     "^.-"

<:      0.0 

<3  :>  ;}
```

A cute collection of emoticons that allegedly returns null. Does anyone whose C-fu is better than mine explain how it works?

Comment: To whomever downvoted and voted to close: I disagree on this question being too localized: It shows valid parts of C++ syntax and is an example of di- and trigraphs as the currently top voted answer shows. Although constructed, I do feel it belongs here.

Comment: IMO, this question belongs on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<:` means `[`, `:>` means `]` (they're digraphs).

`??!` means `|` (it's a trigraph), so `??!??!` is logical `||`

The last `?` on the first line is a conditional operator.

The remainder selects one character from one of the two emoticon strings. It will select from the first one, since regardless of how many `!` and `~` there are in the mess at the start, `anything || 1` is true.

So it actually selects `"^_^"[3]`, which is the nul terminator at the end of the string, which is 0.

Basically the code reads `return ((some mess) || 1) ? "^_^"[3] : "^.-"[1];`, since `0.0 < 3` is true.

[Edit: I just realised (and commented below), it is possible to write a conforming implementation on which `~(expression equal to 0)` has undefined behavior. So to know whether or not this code is strictly conforming, you have to check that neither of the `~` is applied to a zero. In fact `!!!1` is `0`, so the code doesn't strictly conform. It'll work on any implementation you can name, though, since approximately everything uses 2's complement.]

Comment: I had never heard of di- and trigraphs before. Interesting.

Comment: @jurgemaister: the particularly anti-social thing about trigraphs is that (unlike digraphs) they are expanded even inside string literals. Worse, `??/` can extend strings or `//` comments by escaping a quote or newline. Many (most?) compilers disable trigraphs by default, and in code that you're writing it's generally worth enabling warnings for them, because you will *never* write one deliberately. They exist to support character sets and keyboards that don't have all of the characters required to write C.

Comment: I imagine I'm not the only one ignorant about trigraphs, so disabling them sounds like a good thing to do. Handy to know of it given the errors it may cause.

Answer (score 4):

First, replace the trigraphs and alternative tokens with their canonical forms: `??!` becomes `|`, `<:` becomes `[` and `:>` becomes `]`:

```
!!!~!!!!!~!!!1 || 1 ? "^_^"[3] : "^.-"[0.0<3]
```

The first part `<something> || 1` evaluates to true. You can work out what `!!!~!!!!!~!!!1` evaluates to if you like, but it doesn't matter (as long as the behaviour is defined, as noted in the comments). So the result of the conditional operator is the first branch,

```
"_^_"[3]
```

The string literal has four characters, the final one being the zero terminator; so the value of the entire expression is zero.

Comment: "but it doesn't matter", heh, unless you're on a 1s' complement implementation that doesn't support negative zero, in which case `~0` has undefined behavior. So it might matter :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Good spot, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

By removing the trigraphs and digraphs (along with whitespace, and adding a parenthesis on the terniary operator), we get:

int main() {
    return !!!~!!!!!~!!!1||1?("^_^" [3]):"^.-"[0.0 <3];
}

Now all we need to do is remove the unnecessary extra stuff...